# How to prevent double escaping?

Tags: shell, filenames, wildcards, quoting, escape-characters

I'm trying to put a bunch of images together into a pdf. I ran `gm convert *.jpg out.pdf` and it worked, but the images were not in the right order.
I found that `ls -v` orders them correctly so then I tried `` gm convert `ls -v *.jpg` out.pdf ``, but that failed because the files have spaces in the names.

So I checked the ls options and tried `` gm convert `ls -Qv *.jpg` out.pdf `` and `` gm convert `ls -bv *.jpg` out.pdf `` but both failed because, as far as I can tell, the file names got escaped twice (using \" in the first case, and \\ before space in the 2nd case).
Why is this happening, and how can I get the file names escaped correctly, i.e. only once? I'm using zsh if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use escaping this way. You can use quotes or backslashes for something that understands them like the shell parsing.

There's nothing to escape the word splitting done upon variable expansion or command substitution (which is different from the shell parsing (tokenising) of a command line).

What you can do is either change the internal field delimiter `$IFS` to split on newline characters only (but note that except with `zsh`, you also need to disable filename generation (though not for the expansion of `*.jpg` obviously) which is the other thing done upon unquoted command substitution, unless you can guarantee that no filename contains globbing characters):

```
set -f # disable filename generation
IFS='
' # set IFS  to newline character
IFS=$'\n' # alternative for ksh/zsh/bash
gm convert $(set +f; ls -v ./*.jpg) out.pdf # you also need ./ in case file
                                            # names start with -
```

(that assumes none of the file names contain newline characters)

`set -f` in `zsh` (unless in sh/ksh emulation) disables reading `rc` files (think `zsh -f`, `csh -f`), which has no effect once the shell is already started so is harmless.

With `zsh`, you can shorten that to:

```
gm convert ${(f)"$(ls -v ./*.jpg)"} out.pdf
```

`(f)` short for `(ps:\n:)` is to split on newline characters.

Alternatively, you could use `ls` quoting to build a shell command line (shell code in shell syntax if you like) to pass to `eval` which would let the shell evaluate it and run it:

With `ksh93`, `zsh` or `bash`:

```
eval "images=($(ls --quoting-style=shell -v ./*.jpg))"
gm convert "${images[@]}" out.pdf
```

But with `zsh`, you could simply do:

```
gm convert ./*.jpg(n) out.pdf
```

`(n)` is a globbing qualifier that tells the shell to sort the generated file names numerically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. The (n) feature is awesome, too bad it gets so complicated in the general case. I guess generating the whole command would be easier to get my head around, something like ``echo gm convert `ls -Qv *.jpg` out.pdf`` and either redirect it into a file or copy and paste the output.

Comment: ...or simply pipe it to sh :)

Comment: @aditsu, that's what eval's for. But that wouldn't work like that. Above you're still splitting the output of `ls` and `echo` (like `eval` would do as well) concatenates them with **one** space (instead of what caused the splitting in the first place). Also `-Q` is not the write quoting style for the shell (see for instance files with `$` or `\`` or newline in their name) and `echo` expands backslash sequences.

Comment: Hmm it happens to work in my case, but I guess it's not a general solution. I find the eval solution confusing because of the "${images[@]}" part.

Comment: How does set -f work? I tried `set -f;echo *.jpg` and it still listed all the files. Or do I need to use it in a script?

Comment: Sorry, there was a problem with my code, `set -f` disables globbing, so it disable globbing for `*.jpg` as well. With zsh it's `set -F` (`set -f` only in sh/ksh emulation), but it's not needed unless in sh/ksh emulation because `zsh` doesn't do globbing upon command substitution by default like the other shells do. `"${images[@]}"` can be written `$images` in zsh (and in zsh only), it expands to the elements of the array. In zsh, `$images` expands to the non-empty elements while in other shells, it expands to the first element only.